# Codeigniter Remove index and add css

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi This is my website link 
http://webscarlets.com/ci/welcome

I'm new to codeigniter. I removed the index.php from the url. 
To remove the index.php from url i used the following code. I get this code from the codeigniter user guide

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/index.php/$1 [L]
```

But the css is not loading. Here is my configuration settings

```
//autoload.php
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','html');

//config.php   
$config['base_url'] = 'http://webscarlets.com/ci/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

//constants.php
define("LAYOUT_URL","http://webscarlets.com/ci/");

//view.sphp 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo LAYOUT_URL; ?>css/all.css">
```

Please review my codes and guide to complete this task.

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: first of all echo the `base_url()` so that you can sure about the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment css link is **http://webscarlets.com/ci/application/css/all.css** so make sure there is css files is placed on this path or put css file on root folder and use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url; ?>css/all.css">` instead of Layout url.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's working great. Now if i want to put the css, images into application folder means what should i do?

Comment: Put the images folder on same directory where css folder is placed and use these images like images/abc.jpg in the css clsss

Comment: Placing the images and css files in the root folder is the healthy way to program in codeigniter? Because i don't about these. i'm a beginner

Comment: ya there is no problem in this...It will work without any problem....In case this answer helps you, you can upvote or accept this answers to make it easy for all users

Answer (score 1):

As you ask in your question, you want to remove the index.php string in the url, so in .htaccess file you will have something similar to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Also you say you have your css in

```
css/all.css
```

To allow CI to load the css you must permit it in .htaccess file, adding the folder that you don't want to be rewrited. In your case, and supposing that your *all.css* file is in **css folder** you must write the next .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/index.php/$1 [L]
```

In other hand, if you will going to store the css file in other dir, for example assets, you must be sure you added that in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/index.php/$1 [L]
```

And remember that's all I said to you can be applied to images, js or css. **Only remember to add the folder where are stored to .htaccess file**.

Once you do that, you can add the css in your view using the base_url() helper or writing directly

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ci/css/all.css">
```

Please be careful about where is located your CI app.

I hope it will help you. Good luck!